# Is form action attribute allowed with empty value in HTML5 or XHTML5?

Tags: html, forms, action, w3c

Is form *action* attribute allowed with **empty value** in HTML5 or XHTML5?
I found contradicted two articles in Japanese, one says it is allowed, the other says not.

**[Allowed](http://honttoni.blog74.fc2.com/blog-entry-136.html)**
This even says attributes themselves can be omitted.

**[Not Allowed](http://w0s.jp/diary/163)**
This information seems to be older than the other.

I tried to search the latest official information in English on W3C sites, but failed to find it.
Does anyone know how it is?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-fs-action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `action` attribute of the `form` element cannot have an empty value specified, the specifications are clear: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-action. Its value must be a [valid URL](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/), at least surrounded by [white space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).

However, it isn't mandatory: you can not define it, the from data will be sent to the same URL of the document.

I don't understand Japanese, so I can't tell you anything about the two articles you mentioned, sorry about that. Maybe one refers to an old draft of the specification.